# REQUIRED and RANGE validation in ASP.NET MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just started learning ASP.NET MVC (*NOT core*), and can't seem to validate models. A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDatabasePractice.Models
{
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Employee ID")]
        [Range(100000, 999999)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter in last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter in email address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Email")]
        [Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "Confirm email doesn't match email address")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter in password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password length incorrect")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The `[Display(Name = "...")]` part works perfectly fine in the final form, but the `[Range]`, `[Compare]` and `[Required]` just don't work. (`[DataType(DataType.Password)]` still works, though).

Passing them more parameters like `ErrorMessage = "This field is required"` doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any errors whatsoever.

For those asking, this is the code in the controller, extremely basic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCDatabasePractice.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SignUp()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Employee Sign Up";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code in the view file:

```
@model MVCDatabasePractice.Models.EmployeeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Sign Up";
}

<h2>SignUp</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee Model</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: you've got to give more information than that. Why do you think it is not working? Show controller code, maybe the break point in the debugger. With *just* the model, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Have you downloaded and added the validation scripts to the project - `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` and referenced the bundle in the View like `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/YourjQueryValidateBundle")
}` ?

Comment: Thanks! I had both mentioned files downloaded, I just never used ``@section Scripts {     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }`` to reference the bundle. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to [Jaggan_j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2093481/jaggan-j).

I double-checked to make sure I had the `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` files in the `Scripts` folder, and then used
`@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }` (`jqueryval` is the name of the bundle, which I checked in the `BundleConfig.cs` file under `App_Start`)
in my View to reference the jquery bundle.

Everything works perfectly fine now.